# Haskell: Could not find module ‘Data.List.Split’

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to split a list in Haskell and I want to import Data.List.Split. 
However I'm presented with this error:

```
a.hs:2:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Data.List.Split’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
2 | import Data.List.Split
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

This is my code:

```
module PoemLines where
import Data.List.Split

firstSen = "Tyger Tyger, burning bright\n"
secondSen = "In the forests of the night\n"
thirdSen = "What immortal hand or eye\n"
fourthSen = "Could frame thy fearful symmetry?"
sentences = firstSen ++ secondSen ++ thirdSen ++ fourthSen

myLines :: String -> [String]
myLines x = undefined
shouldEqual =
 [ "Tyger Tyger, burning bright"
 , "In the forests of the night"
 , "What immortal hand or eye"
 , "Could frame thy fearful symmetry?"
 ]

main :: IO ()
main =
 print $ "Are they equal? "
         ++ show (myLines sentences == shouldEqual)
```

How do I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: I guess you did not install the `split` package with stack or cabal.

Comment: How are you trying to compile or interpret this code? Do you have a `.cabal` or `stack.yaml` file? What does the file look like?